# How to get the location data in iOS even if the gps location is not changing

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

for my iOS app i need to get the continuos stream of location data even if the device location is not changing or it is steady. I am able to get the location data successfully using following code:

```
- (void)getLocation
{
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        Lon = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    }
    else{NSLog(@"current location is nil");};
}
```

However, even if I call the `getLocation` method like every second when device is steady it does not invoke the `didUpdateToLocation` method I guess, and thus, does not record the gps data. It only records when device actually moves. How can I make sure that it record the data every second even if the gps location is not changing. or in other words how to check if it is calling `didUpdateToLocation` method

I understand that the data would be repetitive but still is it possible to get it every second.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First of all try to use the `-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations`
 function. The one you are using is deprecated. Replace the newLocation variable with `[locations lastObject]`. As soon as you call the [locationManager startUpdatingLocation] the didUpdateLocations should be invoked. If this doesn't work try to add `locationManager.distanceFilter = 1; // distance in meters` before you invoke the startUpdateLocatons

Comment: Also make sure that the locationManager object is not nil by the time you call getLocation function

Comment: Can you not assume that if there is no update, they are in the same location?

Comment: is it possible to get the location previous to lastObject location or does this array stores all the locations changes CLLocation has encountered?

Comment: @Zolnoor but how to check the updates

Comment: I am pasting the corresponding section from Apple Developer: If updates were deferred or if multiple locations arrived before they could be delivered, the array may contain additional entries. The objects in the array are organized in the order in which they occurred. Therefore, the most recent location update is at the end of the array. More information can be found here: (https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423615-locationmanager)

Comment: @kgkoutio Cool Thanks.